# Merging abstract and final methods through multiple inheritance

Tags: c++, abstract-class, multiple-inheritance

Consider the following program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

class WheeledVehicle {
  public:
    virtual void drive() const { printf("Default driving implementation."); }
};

class GroundVehicle : public WheeledVehicle {
  public:
    void drive() const final { WheeledVehicle::drive(); }
};

class DrivableAssaultMachine {
  public:
    virtual void drive() const = 0;
    void fire_cannon();
};

class FighterJet : public DrivableAssaultMachine {
  public:
    void fly() const { printf("flying my plane.\n"); }
    void drive() const override { fly(); }
};

class Tank : public DrivableAssaultMachine, public GroundVehicle {
};

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  make_shared<Tank>()->drive();
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I would like to make this program compile using **only** modifications to `Tank`. If I implement `drive`, then it contradicts the `final` declaration in `GroundVehicle`. If I don't implement it, then `Tank` is abstract and can't be instantiated. Is there some other way to get `Tank`'s inherited implementation of `drive()` be recognized in the context of inheriting from `DrivableAssaultMachine`?

**EDIT:** Renamed everything to provide a more concrete example.

Comment: Why not deriving `Drivable Tank` from `GroundVehicle`? Override function `drive()` in `DrivableTank` if you'll use it or just leave it, it will be visible to all of the classes derived from `DrivableTank` as well(it will continue to be override-able as it descends from `Vehicle`).

Comment: Even with the updated names, the design still doesn't make sense. Aren't all vehicles drivable? That means that the abstract `drive` function should be in the `Vehicle` class, and maybe have a `Shooter` class with an abstract `fire` function, and the `Tank` class inherits from `GroundVehicle` and `Shooter`.

Comment: Please do not edit a solution into your question. Instead, post it as a separate answer below. Also, in future, please strive to make your original question as complete as possible, so that your question does not have to undergo the radical edits seen here. It invalidates existing answers, and undermines the effort users have gone to to write those answers.

Comment: @Matt Done, thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by creating a diamond hierarchy and using virtual inheritance. Here is a simplified visualization of my hierarchy from the question:

```
                    WheeledVehicle
                                \
  DrivableAssaultMachine      GroundVehicle
                       \     /
                        Tank
```

Although my feeling is that the compiler should be able to resolve ambiguities and virtualization here, the fact is that it can't. My solution is to fully connect the diamond and use virtual inheritance:

```
                       Drivable
                      /       \
                     /       WheeledVehicle
                    /          /
  DrivableAssaultMachine      GroundVehicle
                       \     /
                        Tank
```

Here is the final program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

class Drivable {
  public:
    virtual void drive() const = 0;
};

class WheeledVehicle : public virtual Drivable {
  public:
    virtual void drive() const override { printf("Default driving implementation.\n"); }
};

class GroundVehicle : public WheeledVehicle {
  public:
    void drive() const final { WheeledVehicle::drive(); }
};

class DrivableAssaultMachine : public virtual Drivable {
  public:
    void fire_cannon();
};

class Tank : public DrivableAssaultMachine, public GroundVehicle {
};

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  make_shared<Tank>()->drive();
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

In general, the workaround appears to be using simple virtual interfaces near the root of your inheritance tree, and combining or complexifying interfaces as you get toward the leaves.

Answer (score 4):

Conceptual flaw:

`class FighterJet` could not be derived from `DrivableAssaultMachine` as
`DrivableAssaultMachine` is derived from `class GroundVehicle`.

`FighterJet` are not `GroundVehicle`s.

You should differentiate `GroundVehicles` and `AirVehicles` and add: `drive` and `fly` as member functions in those and **then** derive `Tank` from the first and `FighterJet`, from the second.

### After the n-th Edit:

You've just took under consideration what I've told you and changed the inheritance structure, braking `DrivableAssaultMachine` from `WheeledVehicle`

### Final Answers:

> If I implement `drive()`, then it contradicts the `final` declaration in `GroundVehicle`.

`drive()` is redundant in `FighterJet`(as it has `fly()` available), removing it from there will allow you to override it in `Tank`.

The `virtual drive` in `DrivableAssaultMachine` has nothing to do with the `drive()` inherited from `WheeledVehicle`. So there should be ambiguity when try to override it in `Tank`, as it has as base classes both `DrivableAssaultMachine` and indirectly `WheeledVehicle`.

Note: In general your abstract class should provide basic functionality, for example member function: a virtual `move()` and then the derived classes should wrap it up(override it) and specialize it to their needs, for example: `drive()` and `fly()`. Your only tools to specify visibility and accessibility is via the `public`, `private` and `protected` specifier during the definition and the inheritance.

Comment: `DrivableAssaultMachine` is not derived from `GroundVehicle`. `DrivableAssaultMachine` is an interface - it only defines methods that are available. It does not provide default functionality.

Comment: @Jake this just happened now!

Comment: @Jake what you should,do,  at least, is to delete the `Edit 2` from your question as it didn't made any sense!

Comment: @Jake fair enough, just ask your questions without editing them continuously to reflect the "unjustified attacks". Sorry for the aggressive tone, I was just trying to help :)

Comment: I do appreciate you taking the time to help, so thank you, and I'm sorry if I came off aggressive as well.

Comment: "drive() is redundant in FighterJet" - The point of implementing an interface is that I can store it in a context where I **don't know** that `drive()` is redundant. I can have a list `std::list<DrivableAssaultMachine>` where all I care about is that they can be driven and they can fire a cannon. I should be able to add a hundred different interfaces to my class for this purpose so that I can use it in different settings and only care/know about the intended purpose in those settings.

Comment: @Jake but then what is the functionality of `fly()`?

Comment: Well, for example, I could have `FighterJet` inherit from some interface `Flyable` and then put it in a list `std::list<Flyable>` somewhere else.

Comment: This answer isn't exactly what I went with, but your insight regarding using simpler methods for abstract classes makes sense to me and led me in the right direction. So I am going to accept this. Thanks for your help and for the discussion.

Answer (score -2):

**C++ is *not* Java.**

The inheritance and overriding in C++ has to be more explicit than in Java. (I think C++ is right here.)

In C++, two virtual functions declarations `foo` (with the same signature) are considered **homonyms, distinct, unrelated functions** unless one declaration overrides the other.

```
struct B1 {
    virtual void foo();
};

struct B2 {
    virtual void foo();
};

struct D : B1, B2 {
    void bar();
};
```

`D` has two inherited declarations of a member function with the same signature, and unqualified calls to `foo()` within `D::bar()` would be ambiguous, but the definition of class `D` is well formed. *There is no problem with having potential ambiguities in C++*, only ambiguous calls are disallowed.

This means that you can derive from base classes with unrelated homonyms. You just have to avoid ambiguous calls.

Even when both declarations of `foo()` come from the same class:

```
struct B {
    virtual void foo();
};

struct Left : B {
};

struct Right : B {
};

struct D : Left, Right {
    void bar();
};
```

Both inherited declarations of `B::foo()` are simply homonyms: they come from the same class, but they in two distinct base classes. C++ lets you have homonyms. **The compiler doesn't believe the functions do the same thing** or are related in any way other than having the same name, explicit argument list (the arguments inside parentheses), implicit `this` argument type (of type `Base*`), and being declared by the same declaration in the source file!

Of course, there is potential ambiguity: if you try to call `foo` on a derived object, or try to convert (implicitly, or explicitly with `static_cast` or a C-style cast) a derived pointer to an ambiguous base class pointer.

[Note: some people call that "diamond inheritance" (although the inheritance graph is a tree not a "diamond"), or "dreaded diamond" (it's only dreaded if you don't understand MI in C++) or "diamond of death" (who died?) or "diamond of end of the world" (now I'm making stuff up, but it's only slightly more over the top than "diamond of death"). Seriously, don't freak out people with a potential ambiguity. --end note]

This means that you can derive from base classes with unrelated derivation of the same non virtual base class. You just have to avoid ambiguous calls and ambiguous conversions. (This can happen when two classes derive from the same utility class like `refcounted_base`.)

In Java, multiple inheritance of classes doesn't exist, but multiple interface inheritance does, and distinct declarations of a given (pure virtual) function are synonyms:

```
interface I {
    void foo();
}

class Base {
    public void foo() { }
}

class Der extends Base implements I {
}
```

Here `Base::foo()` will implement `I::foo()` even if neither `Base` nor `I` names or knows about one another. This never happens in C++.

> Although my feeling is that the compiler should be able to resolve ambiguities and virtualization here,

Your feeling is based on an incorrect notion of C++ inheritance model; the compiler cannot know your intent. You gave the compiler two different declarations, **just because they are homonyms does not mean you intended to have synonyms**.

By inheriting from a common interface (with virtual inheritance as you should with interfaces), you are telling the compiler that there is only one feature `drive`. All uses of `drive` are synonyms now.

Comment: You argument doesn't apply because one of the base functions is pure virtual in my example.

Comment: In my first example, `DrivableAssaultMachine` has a pure virtual `foo` and `WheeledVehicle` has a virtual `foo`. `Tank` inherits from both. The pure virtual `foo` is a contract - `Tank` must be abstract or have some `foo` implementation available. The virtual `foo` of `WheeledVehicle` is such an implementation. There is no ambiguity here, just a compiler error because the compiler doesn't inspect the base classes.

Comment: Why do you believe that? I explained why there is an ambiguity. There are two different virtual functions.

Comment: Perhaps you've convinced yourself that there is an ambiguity to the compiler. That doesn't mean there is intrinsic ambiguity in the program.

Comment: I haven't convinced myself. I have clearly explained why it's the case. Also, I have worked in the std C++ committee, so I know what I am talking about.

Comment: In my first example, `Tank` fulfills the contract enforced by `DrivableAssaultMachine`, because it provides a single, callable implementation of `foo`. However the program does not compile. You do not address this specific case, which is at the core of my original question. If you want to continue this discussion, please provide a clear explanation regarding why you believe that `Tank` does not fulfill the contract. Please word your explanation in terms of the original question, using the example provided there. And finally, please keep Java out of this discussion. It is not relevant here.

Comment: "_why you believe that Tank does not fulfill the contract_" This is what my answer is about.